# UITableViewCell contains dynamic (Image , Title & Subtitle ) produce shaking while scrolling

Tags: image, scroll, heightforrowatindexpath

Firstly I tried using autolayout + estimated row height . But did not work.
So I again I did every things  using frame & calculate height in heightForRowAtIndex method & remove all autolayout on cell but this solution also not working.
My Tableview has following Conditions.
1.In my tableview  I register 3 custom cell 
2.One custom header form xib
3.Images on cell come in different size (too large or to small) , So I have to resize in 100*100 areas with top left align

Answer (score 0):

My be this link is help for you https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: raywender demo app is more shaking when rotate landscape to portrait & scroll

Comment: Thanks Hiren but I shaking problem is also occurred in raywender Demo app when we change orientation